# Como usar uma função javascript multiplas vezes para diferentes divs e inputs com classes diferentes?

Tags: javascript, html

Estou criando um site de ecommerce dentro desse site tenho divs com produtos onde tenho botões para alterar valores de inputs mas tenho que replicar funções em javascript e alterar nomes de classes das divs toda vez. Esse é o problema se eu tiver 100 produtos irei precisar replicar 100 vezes. Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso sem replicar para cada produto? Vou postar aqui a parte do código que eu preciso de ajuda.

Parte Do Produto

```
    <span>Preço de Produto:</span>
<span class="valor" id="Valor">200</span>€<br>
    <br>
    <input type="image" src="https://liedobom.pt/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/1-5.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100">
    <br>
        <input id="Menos" type="button" onclick="Menos();Resultado()" value="-">
        <input type="number" name="Qtd" id="Qtd" maxlength="4" value="0" size="4">
        <input id="Mais" type="button" onclick="Mais();Resultado()" value="+"><br><br>
        <span>Total</span><br>
        <div class="Ajudante">
            <input type="number" name="" id="PPTTL" value="0" readonly><br><br>
        </div>
<input type="button" onclick="Exibir()" value="Add Carrinho"><br><br>
<input type="button" value="Comprar">
```

Javascript

```
//Produto 1///
function Menos(){
    var Qtd = document.getElementById("Qtd").value;
            document.getElementById("Qtd").value = Qtd - 1;
            if(document.getElementById("Qtd").value <= 0){
                document.getElementById("Qtd").value = 0;
            }
    }

    function Mais(){
        var Qtd = document.getElementById("Qtd").value;
        mais = 1;
        document.getElementById("Qtd").value = Qtd +++ mais;
        if(document.getElementById("Qtd").value <= 0){
            document.getElementById("Qtd").value = 0;
        }
    }

    function Resultado(){
    var Qtd = document.getElementById("Qtd").value;
            var Vlr =  document.getElementById("Valor").innerHTML;
                document.getElementById("PPTTL").value = Qtd * parseInt(Vlr);
    }
```

Comment: Este site é em português, portanto traduza a sua pergunta.

Comment: Muito Obrigada Pela Dica ;)

Comment: Ao inves de você buscar os itens por ID, busca pela classe e depois faz o cascading pra pegar o item q vc precisa.

Comment: Você pode adicionar o evento de click do seu botão no js. Quando o botão for clicado você tem a referência do elemento HTML, aí pode navegar e achar os valores que precisa. Olhe [isso](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener).

Answer (score 0):

Defina uma classe ou atributo personalizado para cada action dispatch(disparador de ações) dentro do seu container de informações do produto e então selecione todos os elementos que possuem essa definida característica, itere sobre eles e ative os eventos...

Exemplo com atributo personalizado:

HTML:

```
    <!-- Atenção: como são múltiplos containers com ações semelhantes, então você não deve utilizar o atributo ID como está atualmente, pois o ID deve ser um atributo de identificação única e exclusiva de um elemento(tal como um CPF)! Se você tiver algum estilo sendo aplicado os ID's "Menos", "Mais" e outros eu sugiro que mude para classes. -->

    <!-- Definimos um atributo de ativação e seleção para os listeners... -->
    <!-- O atributo "action" configura em qual ação os "dispatchers" serão executados! -->
    <input data-action="click" data-dispatchers="menos;resultado" type="button" value="-">


    <input data-action="click" data-dispatchers="mais;resultado" type="button" value="+"><br><br>
```

JS:

```
    // Selecionamos os elementos que tem um ACTION ativado...
    const actionDispatchers = document.querySelectorAll('[data-action]');

    // Iteramos sobre os elementos selecionados acima...
    actionDispatchers.forEach(el => {
      // Capturamos o tipo de ação que será esperada...
      let action = el.getAttribute('data-action');
      // Capturamos os despachantes configurados para disparar e os fragmentamos...
      let dispatchers = el.getAttribute('data-dispatchers').split(';');

      // Ativamos o evento com o tipo de ação esperada...
      el.addEventListener(action, e => {
        // Iteramos sobre os despachantes capturados...
        dispatchers.forEach(dispatch => {
          // Executamos um switch case no despachante para definir qual rotina executar...
          switch (dispatch) {
            case "mais":
              Mais();
              break;
            case "menos":
              Menos();
              break;
            case "resultado":
              Resultado();
              break;
            default:
              return null;
          }
        });
      }, false);
    });
```

Bom, isso é tudo, executando o código acima após do carregamento completo da página bastará descrever qual ação e despachantes deverão ser executados e definir as rotinas previamente para que sejam chamadas devidamente...